# If statement called when comparison of template parameter is false

Tags: c++, class, templates, if-statement, compiler-errors

I'm writing a templated matrix class using C++14. This class has three template parameters: the type of data stored (dtype), the number of rows (N) and the number of columns (M).

The class signature is

```
template<class dtype, size_t N, size_t M>
class Matrix
```

I've written a determinant member function that calls specific cases when a template parameter has a certain value. For example, when the number of rows is 1 it returns a copy of the matrix itself. Alternatively, when the number of rows is 2 or 3 it returns a 1x1 matrix of the same datatype with the determinant. Finally, when the number of rows is more than 3 it uses a recursive method to calculate the determinant based on the cofactor expansion of the determinant.

I am doing this as an exercise to better learn C++14 so I'd be very grateful for some help.

The code snippet causing issues is this part right here:

```
Matrix<dtype, 1, 1> det() const {
    if (N != M || N >= 12) {
        return Matrix<dtype, 1, 1>();
    } else if (N == 1) {
        return this->copy();
    } else if (N == 2) {
        return Matrix<dtype, 1, 1>(this->get(0, 0) * this->get(1, 1) - this->get(0, 1) * this->get(1, 0));
    } else if (N == 3) {
        return Matrix<dtype, 1, 1>(
                this->get(0, 0) * (this->get(1, 1) * this->get(2, 2) - this->get(1, 2) * this->get(2, 1)) -
                this->get(0, 1) * (this->get(1, 0) * this->get(2, 2) - this->get(1, 2) * this->get(2, 0)) +
                this->get(0, 2) * (this->get(1, 0) * this->get(2, 1) - this->get(1, 1) * this->get(2, 0)));
    } else if (N < 12) {
        Matrix<dtype, 1, 1> determinant;
        Matrix<dtype, N - 1, N - 1> sub_matrix;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            sub_matrix = this->drop_cross(i, i);
            Matrix<dtype, 1, 1> sub_det(sub_matrix.det());
            if (i % 2 == 0) determinant = determinant + (this->get(0, i) * sub_det);
            else if (i % 2 == 1) determinant = determinant - (this->get(0, i) * sub_det);
        }
        return determinant;
    }
}
```

This function is called by this code:

```
#include "lin_alg_classes.h"

int main() {
    Matrix<double, 3, 3> test3(1.0, true);

    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << test3.det();

    return 0;
}
```

And gives the following output:

```
In file included from C:\Users\ekin4\CLionProjects\mt_grav\main.cpp:5:0:
C:\Users\ekin4\CLionProjects\mt_grav\lin_alg_classes.h: In instantiation of 'Matrix<dtype, 1ull, 1ull> Matrix<dtype, N, M>::det() const [with dtype = double; long long unsigned int N = 3ull; long long unsigned int M = 3ull]':
C:\Users\ekin4\CLionProjects\mt_grav\main.cpp:29:28:   required from here
C:\Users\ekin4\CLionProjects\mt_grav\lin_alg_classes.h:132:31: error: could not convert 'Matrix<dtype, N, M>::copy<double, 3ull, 3ull>()' from 'Matrix<double, 3ull, 3ull>' to 'Matrix<double, 1ull, 1ull>'
             return this->copy();
```

What I don't understand is why it is calling the N = 1 case when it should be calling the N < 12 case. I have checked braces, parentheses and semicolons, and they are all correct, but for the life of me I don't understand what is happening.

Comment: With a sufficiently recent compiler, you could use [`constexpr if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If). Outside that, the program must still be well-formed at compile time, even if some branches are not in fact taken at run-time. Before `constexpr if`, a typical approach to compile-time dispatch is template specialization.

Comment: Also where is defined M and N in  your code... **Do you really expect us to guess the 3 missing lines**. In any case, as already explained by someone else, the above code won't works if M and N are template parameters as you don't use `constexpr if`.

Comment: @Phil1970 sorry, I thought it was clear from the first paragraph, but I'll edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @Serge when N==1 then `this->copy()` returns a `Matrix<dtype, 1, 1>`. I do believe that, as @IgorTandetnik said, this is an issue with using a template parameter in an if statement that is defined at compile time. So the correct method is to use constexpr, but that's c++17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pre c++17 (`if constexpr`) you can use SFINAE and enable/disable different versions of `det()` according the values of `N` and `M`.

Something like (sorry: not tested)

```
template <std::size_t A = N, std::size_t B = M>
std::enable_if_t<(A != B) || (A > 11U), Matrix<dtype, 1, 1>> det() const
 { return Matrix<dtype, 1, 1>(); }

template <std::size_t A = N, std::size_t B = M>
std::enable_if_t<(A == B) && (A == 1U), Matrix<dtype, 1, 1>> det() const
 { return this->copy(); }

// other cases
```

Comment: This was perfect! Just adjusted the conditional for my cases and it worked!